# How can i create a new tab via browserAction and then execute a script

Tags: google-chrome, permissions, tabs

I want to create a tab by clicking on the browser action button and then insert a content script or execute a script. So far, its not working well.

Background.html

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) 
{
   chrome.tabs.create({url: "Dreamer.html"}, function(tab)    //Dreamer.html is a file in my extension
   { 
       //Add a script
       chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:'Dreamer.js'});
   });
});
```

Manifest.json

```
{
   "name" : " Dreamer",
   "version" : "0.1",
   "description" : "My extensionr",
   "browser_action" : {"default_icon" : "App/AppData/Images/icon.png", "default_title":"Start   Dreamer" },
   "background_page" : "App/AppData/background.html",
   "content_scripts" :[{"matches":["http://*/*"],"js":["app/view/UIManager.js"]}],
   "permissions": [ "cookies", "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ]
}
```

i get this error in the background page

```
Error during tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "chrome-extension://femiindgnlfpdpajimkmldpgpccngfmd/Dreamer.html". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
```

I would really like to know how to create a tab(new tab) and run a script immediately

**EDIT:**

The kind of application i am creating requires the following actions:

-Allow user to create new tab by clicking the browserAction button
-On creation of the new tab, a file in my extension (Dreamer.html) is opened
-Add a content script or execute a script in the new tab

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you need to *inject* the script? Since both Dreamer.html and Dreamer.js seem to be hardcoded, you could just include `<script type="text/javascript" src="Dreamer.js"></script>` in the former, right?

As a side benefit, if you need it to send info to the background page, you can access it directly with `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` instead of setting up complex listeners that usually come with content scripts, too.

Injecting content scripts is for injecting scripts outside the extension sandbox. Dreamer.html, however, is a part of the extension.

**Edit**

If you do want an (unwieldy) example of how to execute a script in an extension page, see here:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30756#c11

I don't think it applies to your case, however.